# Different (swapped) margins on first page only

Tags: margins, geometry

I have to typeset twosided document (using memoir class) with wider outer margins (designed for some remarks). The problem is, that on the first page these margins have to be swapped, i.e. iner (left) margin is wider. Unfortunately, it is not possible to manually break first page (page contains longtable), so there is no simple way to  use \newgeometry (AFAIK).

Hopefully the explanation is clear, there si simple non-working MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum, filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, csvsimple, longtable, afterpage}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{top=10cm,bottom=10cm,outer=5cm,inner=1cm}

\begin{filecontents*}{main.csv}
    tableA
    exampleA.csv
    exampleA.csv   % Added line
    exampleA.csv   % Added line
    exampleA.csv   % Added line
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{exampleA.csv}
    colA
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
    f
    g
    h
    i
    j
    k
    l
    m
    n
    o
    p
    q
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
This page has to be with "swaped" margins, i.e. outer=1cm, inner=5cm.
How to do this???

\lipsum[1]

%
% Structure of first page
%
\csvreader[%
    head to column names,
    separator=semicolon]{main.csv}{}{%

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First example \tableA
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        string type,
        begin table=\begin{longtable},
        end table=\end{longtable}]{\tableA}
  \end{enumerate}
}


This page (and all following from page number 2) has margins as
defined above, i.e. outer=5cm, inner=1cm.

Unfortunately this page start somwhere inside above loop...

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
Added 3 lines to main.csv.

**Problem:**
Proposed solution doesn't work. Updated MWE compile with errors.

After reading a lot of suggestions I still have no sulution...so I'll appreciate any help or suggestion!

Thank you in advance,

Lubos

Comment: i don't understand well but you can change margin, what you can't do is changing text width.

Comment: Could you be more specific, how to do this, please? (I edited my post to be more clear, hope it helps.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. Using [afterpage](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package.

**Note** in newgeometry `outer+inner=OLDouter+OLDinner` to don't change the textwidth.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1cm,bottom=1cm,outer=5cm,inner=1cm}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1cm,bottom=1cm,outer=1cm,inner=5cm}
\afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

**Update** one can use

```
\oddsidemargin=\evensidemargin
\afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}
```

**Example**

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum, filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, csvsimple, longtable, afterpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=10cm,bottom=10cm,outer=5cm,inner=1cm}

\begin{filecontents*}{main.csv}
    tableA
    exampleA.csv
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{exampleA.csv}
    colA
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
    f
    g
    h
    i
    j
    k
    l
    m
    n
    o
    p
    q
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\oddsidemargin=\evensidemargin
\afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}
This page has to be with "swaped" margins, i.e. outer=1cm, inner=5cm.
How to do this???

\lipsum[1]

%
% Structure of first page
%
\csvreader[%
    head to column names,
    separator=semicolon]{main.csv}{}{%

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First example \tableA
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        string type,
        begin table=\begin{longtable},
        end table=\end{longtable}]{\tableA}
  \end{enumerate}
}


This page (and all following from page number 2) has margins as
defined above, i.e. outer=5cm, inner=1cm.

Unfortunately this page start somwhere inside above loop...

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me, probably because of more complicated structure. On the first page starts longtable environment created using pgfplotstable... Anyway thanks for suggestion!

Comment: P.S. Updated MWE to better respect my actual document structure.

Comment: please make sure that your code compile. it doesn't for me and add example of `main.csv`

Comment: MWE correctd. I'm sorry for confusion! ;(

Comment: @LubošKejzlar answer updated, hope it's ok now.

Comment: you're   welcome :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44301/discussion-between-lubos-kejzlar-and-touhami).